# Wordpress sql : get all category of a post

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

i have a post and it have multi category, how i can get all category of this post by sql query? Thanks so much.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

try

```
select c.*
from wp_categories c
inner join wp_post2cat pc on pc.category_id = c.cat_ID
inner join wp_posts p on pc.post_id = p.id
where p.id = 1
```

Comment: -1 Breaks on every installation with a table prefix != `wp_`. Oh, and on multi-site installations too.

Comment: WordPress has no these tables

Comment: Looks like the `wp_post2cat` table was removed in wordpress version 2.3 (back in 2007) replaced by "terms" related tables.

Answer (score 11):

You can fetch post categories with this SQL :

```
SELECT wt.* FROM wp_posts p
 INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships r ON r.object_id=p.ID
 INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy t ON t.term_taxonomy_id = r.term_taxonomy_id
 INNER JOIN wp_terms wt on wt.term_id = t.term_id
WHERE p.ID=1 AND t.taxonomy="category"
```

Comment: Makes no sense. What you are querying are posts, not categories.

Comment: The query selects `wt.*` which in the current context is `wp_terms` table as defined in the third INNER JOIN.

Answer (score -2):

Check this Code -

```
$post_categories = wp_get_post_categories( $post_id );
$cats = array();

foreach($post_categories as $c){
    $cat = get_category( $c );
    $cats[] = array( 'name' => $cat->name, 'slug' => $cat->slug );
}
```

Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_categories --

Comment: This is not a SQL query.